# Newbie: How to retrieve the count of B object for the below code through lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, lambda

```
List a = List.of(new C(),new B(), new A(), new D(), new B());
```

For example we could see B() two times so the output should be 2 using lambda expression Java 8. Could you please help me.

I have done below code but it is not printing the correct value

```
List a = List.of(new C(),new B(), new A(), new D(), new B());

Object group = a.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        
System.out.println(group);
```

Comment: uhhh have you tried e->e.getClass() instead of Function.Identity() ??? This lets you group by the class. Function.Identity returns the input object which essentially means that you are grouping by each item in the list (although objects can be the same class, they are not the same object)

Comment: Two different B objects aren't identical since they don't seem to implement `equals` and `hashCode`. So how should `groupingBy` know they should be matched?

Answer (score 2):

It is not common and even questionable to fill a list with different types. but to answer your question you could filter the items that are instances of B and count them like:

```
long countOfB = list.stream().filter(i -> i instanceof B).count();
System.out.println(countOfB);
```